# Permission Issue on Ubuntu with Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, apache, ubuntu, actionview

I have a permission issue with Rails on my Ubuntu / Apache / Passenger server.

When I look in my Apache `error_log` file, I see:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Permission denied - /opt/bitnami/apps/tradelogs/tmp/cache/790):
  78:
  79: <% end %>
  80:
  81: <% cache do %>
```

When I look at my directories, I see ([because I Passenger seems to use this as the user](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#user_switching)):

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 bitnami daemon  154 Feb 28 04:42 config.ru
-rwxr-xr-x 1 bitnami daemon   147 Feb 28 04:42 environment.rb
```

And for the tmp/cache directory (there is no `790` file in cache - I'm not sure if I'm suppose to create one):

```
drwxr-xr-x 6 bitnami daemon 4096 Feb 28 04:44 tmp
drwxr-xr-x 4 bitnami daemon 4096 Feb 28 05:42 tmp/cache
```

In my Apache `httpd.conf` file I have this:

```
User bitnami
Group daemon

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /home/bitnami/apps/tradelogs/public
  <Directory /home/bitnami/apps/tradelogs/public>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Things that I have tried:

- `chmod -R 775`, 755 on all directories
- changing the `user` and `group` in the `httpd.conf` to both `daemon`, and to both `bitnami`

Can anyone please help me figure out where my authorizations is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the rights before or after you `rake assets:precompile`

Also, did you restart your web service after having changed the permissions?

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Comment: OK, I did `rake assets:precompile` again, because I compiled before changing the permissions.  But, I'm still getting the same error after doing that, and stopping and restarting the server.

Comment: run `ps aux` and see what user is running the apache/passenger instances

Comment: I ran it, but wasn't 100% sure what command I was looking for - here was the results: https://gist.github.com/ryanchin/5073948

Comment: you don't have Apache there, I am facing the same problem, but I use `ps -ef` and I get `/opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd -f /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd...`